# how to know a file's create time by others

Tags: windows, file, properties

My Dear Friends,

I have a question which puzzled me for quite a long time. It is about the create time of a file. Some one create a file on his PC. There should contain a create time for this file. Like below:

[image]

The if he copied this file to other folders or send this file to others by email. The create time will change. So this create time does not mean the time the file was initially created by the guy, but means the time the file was moved to the folder.

Here comes the question: how can i know the correct initial create time of the file(should be independent of a system)?

Thanks so much for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general way to do this.  The create time for a file is stored on the **filesystem** or in an **archive** (ZIP files store the [last modification date and time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Local_file_header) only, for example).

Sometimes, but not always, a file's creation and modification times are updated when it is copied to another filesystem, device, or archive.  This behavior depends on the tool used to do the copying.  If the original date/time are not preserved during the copy, then that information is lost.

Comment: You're welcome.. if it helped, please click the checkbox to accept my answer :)